# Does ORTC and/or Edge support DataChannel?

Tags: webrtc, ortc

Finding definitive information on ORTC seems difficult, and finding examples even more so.  I need to send strings between iframes and was looking into using WebRTC but in order to support Windows Edge I have been looking into ORTC.  I wanted to see if anyone had successfully used some sort of data channel with ORTC in Windows Edge.  I thought ORTC was specifically for Edge but it seems to define a data channel but Edge does not implement it.

The information I have come across leads me to believe that ORTC cannot do data channels, despite the fact it is listed in their API.

RTCDataChannel defined in the API, section 11.3 http://publications.ortc.org/2016/20161202/)

> The RTCDataChannel interface represents a bi-directional data channel between two peers.

But at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/realtime-communication/object-rtc-api I found:

> Since Microsoft Edge does not implement the data channel, the RTCDataChannel and RTCSctpTransport objects are not supported.

and

> Microsoft Edge currently does not support any of the DataChannel functionality currently defined in the ORTC spec.

Please offer additional resources I can research in order to have a definitive answer.  Also helpful would be any resources stating whether Windows Edge will in the future be supporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/rtcdatachannels/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=rtc&q=data%20channels), ORTC Data channels are "Under consideration".

> Roadmap Priority: Low — We are still evaluating this technology. There
> may be significant spec stabilization, foundational work, or
> additional community input required before we can begin development.

But the real question is:
**Why do you need webRTC in the first place?**

You said that you need to send strings between iframes.
Are the iframes loaded on the same page?

If the answer is yes, you don't need webRTC at all. Take a look at the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) instead.

Comment: We did end up using the [HTML Message Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel) which includes the postMessage API.  Another team had put together a POC they thought could use the RTC technology and I think they got excited about all the features it could bring to the table.  But really in this instance, the HTML MessageChannel is a much better solution.  Glad to see we came to the same answer!